# Set item email field in Podio

Tags: email, field, podio

I'm having a hard time trying to guess how to set the item email field value, since there is nothing about this in the documentation (http://podio.github.io/podio-php/fields/)

I have tried :

```
$item->fields['email']->values = array("type"=>"work","value"=>"a@a.com");
$item->fields['email']->values = array("value"=>"a@a.com");
$item->fields['email']->values = "a@a.com";

$item->fields[$field_id]->value ="i@i.com";
$item->fields[$field_id]->type ="work";

$item->save();
```

Nothing works, please help! Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have figured it out , here is the code that works (if anyone runs into the same problem)

```
$field_id = 'email';
$emails=$item->fields[$field_id]->values;
$item->fields[$field_id]->values =array('value'=>"i@oooo.com",'type'=>'work');

$item->save();
```